# rewriting URLs from .json to .php

Tags: mod-rewrite

I want `http://server/path/app.json?a=foo&b=bar` to map to `http://server/path/foo.php?a=foo&b=bar` using `mod_rewrite`. I have the following incantation in my .htaccess which doesn't give any joy

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^.?]+).json(.*)$ $1.php$2 [L]
```

Suggestions?

Update: Adding rewrite.log and error.log output (comments don't allow formatting)

I get the following in the rewrite.log

```
strip per-dir prefix: /Users/user/Sites/dir/app.json -> app.json
applying pattern '^([^.?]+).json(.*)$' to uri 'app.json'
rewrite 'app.json' -> 'app.php'
add per-dir prefix: app.php -> /Users/user/Sites/dir/app.php
internal redirect with /Users/user/Sites/dir/app.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
```

and the apache server log says

```
The requested URL /Users/user/Sites/dir/app.php was not found on this server.
```

Comment: Do you get anything in the logs?

Comment: this would also match /path/json/fish and rewrite it as /path.php/fish

Comment: comments don't allow any formatting so see the original post above for rewrite.log output

Comment: I take it `/Users/user/Sites/dir/app.php` exists and is readable by apache, what happens if you request the php file directly?

Comment: it works fine, and returns the results correctly.

Answer (score 3):

If I read your question correctly you want:

```
http://server/path/app.json?a=foo&b=bar
```

Going to:

```
http://server/path/foo.php?a=foo&b=bar
```

Sowhen you capture `(app).json` `$1` is `app` and `$2` is your second parenthesis, it's ... nothing (the part between `json` and the `?`). As everything after the question mark is the **QUERY STRING** and cannot be captured here. Your rewriteRule is working on the requested file, not on the **QUERY STRING**. So you didn't captured `foo` anywhere. For the QUERY_STRING you could use the `[QSA]` flag on the rewriteRule, that would simply append `a=foo&b=bar` after your rewrite.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^.?]+).json(.*)$ $1.php$2 [L]
```

Here you tell apache to reuse `$1` (the filename without .json), so `app.json` will get redirected to `app.php`, not `foo.php`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^.?]+).json(.*)$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

Will redirect `app.json?a=b&z=r` to `app.php?a=b&z=r`.

Now if you really need to capture `foo` as the first QUERY_STRING parameter the rule will become harder. But you could do it like that (here instead of the first parameter I detect the parameter **'a='** and capture his value in **%4**):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)(^|&|%26|%20)a(=|%3D)([^&]+)(.*)$
RewriteRule ^([^.?]+).json$ %4.php? [L,QSA]
```